# Unpermitted parameters for nested attributes even though it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I can't seem to save/update nested model attributes via controller, or possibly through the view. I am seeing an error "Unpermitted parameters: (depending upon what model I choose to update goes here, e.g. language)". After days of researching I feel defeated; thanks for any help or direction.

I have one page with many forms for each sections, an edit modal and a delete button.
Everything is done in the index page.

```
Started PATCH "/user_skills/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-29 19:21:05 -0600
Processing by UserSkillsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ArM2OqBIlsM+Vx7YHRq8NtExBp/Z/FmxpRO8xEX8Y9w=",   "user_skill"=>{"language"=>{"title"=>"Ruby", "description"=>"A dynamic, elegant and productive object oriented programming language."}}, "button"=>"", "id"=>"1"}
UserSkill Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "user_skills".* FROM "user_skills"  WHERE "user_skills"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Unpermitted parameters: language
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/user_skills.1
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

So I have one model named user_skill.rb which should update three other different models.

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: user_skills
#
#  id :integer          not null, primary key
#
class UserSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :languages
  has_many :frameworks
  has_many :tools

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :languages, :frameworks, :tools, allow_destroy: true    
end
```

My one controller

```
class UserSkillsController < ApplicationController

def index
    load_user
end

def update
    load_user
    build_skill
    save_skill or render 'user_skills'
end

private

def userskill_scoped
    UserSkill.all
end

def build_skill
    @skill ||= userskill_scoped.build
    @skill.attributes = skill_params
end

def load_user
    @skill ||= UserSkill.find(1)
end

def skill_params
    skill_params = params
    skill_params ? skill_params.require(:user_skill).permit(:id, languages_attributes: [:id, :title, :description, :user_skill_id, :_destroy], frameworks_attributes: [:id, :title, :description, :user_skill_id, :_destroy], tools_attributes: [:id, :title, :description, :user_skill_id, :_destroy]) : {}

end

def save_skill
  notice = @skill.new_record? ? "User skill was successfully created" : "User skills was successfully updated"
  if @skill.save
    redirect_to user_skills_path(@skill), notice: notice
  else
    render 'user_skills'
  end
end
```

This is my form, I've removed some bootstrap divs so that it'll be easier to read. The technology object is passed as a local variable from a collection to this form; it represents an actual instance of a record. e.g

```
<Language id: 1, title: "Ruby", description: "A dynamic, elegant and productive object oriented ...", url: "http://www.ruby-lang.org", image: nil, created_at: "2014-12-19 02:35:10", updated_at: "2014-12-19 19:57:48", user_skill_id: 1>
irb(main):003:0>
```

My form:

```
<%= form_for @skill do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for technology do |f| %> 
  <h4>Title:</h4>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', :required => true %>
  <h4>Content:</h4>
  <%= f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control content-text', :required => true %>
<% end %>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
<%= f.button 'Save', action: 'update', class: "btn btn-default btn-sm", data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Saving..."} %> 
</div>
<% end %>
```

*Update, adding views *

These are my views which leads into the form partial.
"user_skill#index"

```
    <% if notice %>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    <%= notice %>
    </div>  
    <% end %>

    <div>
    <h1 class="title">My Tools</h1>
    <p class="subtitle">Technologies I've worked with...</p>
    <hr>
    <h3>Programming Languages</h3>
    <br>
    <%= render partial: 'user_skills/partials/skills', locals: { a: "languages" } %> 
    <hr>
    <h3>Frameworks</h3>
    <br>
    <%= render partial: 'user_skills/partials/skills', locals: { a: "frameworks"  } %> 
    <hr>
    <h3>Other</h3>
    <br>
    <%= render partial: 'user_skills/partials/skills', locals: { a: "tools"  } %> 
    <br>
    <% ["languages","frameworks","tools"].each do |skill| %>
    <% @skill.send(skill).each do |technology| %>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <%= render 'user_skills/partials/modal', technology: technology %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    </div>
```

_skills partial

```
<% @skill.send(a).each do |technology| %>
<%= render 'user_skills/partials/skill_panels', :technology => technology %> 
            <!-- Modal -->
<%= render 'user_skills/partials/modal', :a => a, :technology => technology %> 
<% end %>
```

_skills_panel

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<%= technology.title %>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<%= technology.description %> 
</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<%= link_to technology.url, technology.url %>
<%= render 'user_skills/partials/edit_buttons', technology: technology %> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

edit_button partial

```
<div class="col-xs-8 pull-right">
<div class="pull-right edit_skill">
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target='#edit_modal<%= "_#{technology.title.gsub(' ','').gsub('.','_')}" %>'>Edit</button>
```

```
<%= button_to "Delete", @skill, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete?"}, class: "btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" %> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

modal partial

```
<div class="modal fade" id='edit_modal_<%= technology.title.gsub(' ','').gsub('.','_')%>' tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
<h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Skills</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<%= render partial: 'form', locals: { technology: technology} %> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doing `skill_params ? x : y` makes no sense at all. `skill_params` (and `params` itself) can *never* be a falsy value, so you will *always* choose the first branch of the ternary `?:` operator. Get rid of that and just return `params.require(...).permit(...)`

Comment: Ok removing that, and I'll update to add my views meagar.

Comment: **Update** It seems the rails helper method fields_for was generating the wrong html input names for each of my forms; I had to customize them and retouched the params hash for the deeply nested attributes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your inputs and your `.reqire(...).permit(...)` don't match at all.

Your incoming params look like this:

```
user_skill: { ..., languages: { ... } }
```

While your expected params look like this:

```
...require(:user_skill).permit(..., languages_attributes: ...
```

That mismatch between `languages` and `languages_attributes` is actually important. Those things need to match or Rails throws out the unmatching param. The absence or presence of `_attributes` matters as much as any other set of characters in matching parameter names.

The reason for the mismatch is that your form isn't set up correctly. I cannot tell why because you haven't included anything in your HTML to indicate where `languages` is supposed to be coming from.

Comment: As per the rails guides http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html it seems to recommend the model_attributes in the params hash; which gave me the assumptions that this will create connections between the models and params. Would renaming to permit(:id, language: [:title, :description]...) help?

Comment: @user2712769 That would allow the parameter to pass through, but that wouldn't allow it to work with the model. The model needs the incoming attributes for a nested model to be called `<model>_attributes`.

Comment: I see user_skill[language][title] in the html generated from my form_for and fields_for helper methods; however in my params method in the controller, rails docs specifies to use languages_attributes etc. So if the naming is the issue, is there a way to customize or ensure that the generated html becomes user_skill[languages_attributes][title] or at least accepted in order for me to overcome the unpermitted error? Sry I've only been learning rails for two months now, I know my understanding is not so good yet.